# Why is my RNN learning to classify all inputs as only 1 of 2 possible classifications?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have written my first TensorFlow implementation of an RNN that takes as input random sequences which are either increasing or decreasing. The training labels are a single integer corresponding to each sequence with 1 being an increasing sequence and 0 decreasing. As my model trains, it quickly leans towards classifying every sequence as decreasing and I cannot figure out why. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import random

sequenceLength = 5     # Input Dimension
maxNum = 1000          # Must be >= than (sequenceLength - 1)
outputDim = 1
hiddenDim = 16
learningRate = 0.1
trainingIterations = 10000
batchSize = 10
displayStep = 1000

def generateData():
    data = []
    labels = []
    for _ in range(batchSize):
        type = (1 if random.random() < 0.5 else 0)
        temp = []
        if type == 1:
            labels.append([1])
            temp.append(random.randint(0, maxNum - sequenceLength + 1))
            for i in range(1, sequenceLength):
                temp.append(random.randint(temp[i - 1] + 1, maxNum - sequenceLength + i + 1))
            data.append(temp)
        if type == 0:
            labels.append([0])
            temp.append(random.randint(0 + sequenceLength - 1, maxNum))
            for i in range(1, sequenceLength):
                temp.append(random.randint( 0 + sequenceLength - i - 1, temp[i - 1] - 1))
            data.append(temp)
    return data, labels

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, sequenceLength], name="input")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, outputDim], name="label")

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hiddenDim, outputDim]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([outputDim]))

cell = rnn.BasicRNNCell(hiddenDim)
outputs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, [x], dtype=tf.float32)
prediction = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(outputs[0], W + b))

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learningRate).minimize(loss)

correctPrediction = tf.equal(tf.round(prediction), y)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPrediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(trainingIterations):
        batchX, batchY = generateData()
        dict = {x: batchX, y : batchY}
        session.run(optimiser, feed_dict=dict)
        if i % displayStep == 0:
            print("Predictions:\t" + str(session.run(tf.transpose(tf.round(prediction)), dict)))
            print("Labels:\t\t" + str(session.run(tf.transpose(y), dict)) + "\n")
        #     batchAccuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=dict)
        #     batchLoss = session.run(loss, feed_dict=dict)
        #     print("Iteration: " + str(i) + "\nAccuracy: " + str(batchAccuracy) + "\nLoss: " + str(batchLoss) + "\n")
```

As I have said, this is my first implementation using TensorFlow so, although I am well aware of how an RNN works, I am still quite lost with the high-level abstraction that we interact with TensorFLow on. It is my calculations of `prediction`, `loss`, `correctPrediction` and `accuracy` that I am most unsure about. Is the way that I am using the sigmoid function twice ok? One time to produce a probability for my prediction, and again to calculate the cross entropy between my prediction (as the probability) and the label.

*EDIT*

I have just noticed that, on very rare occasions, without changing any of the code, the RNN quickly learns to classify the sequences correctly.

Comment: For questions specifically addressing the design and training process of machine learning models, consider asking instead on [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your learning rate is too large. I decreased the learning rate to

```
learningRate = 0.01
```

In addition, you don't need to apply sigmoid here

```
prediction = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(outputs[0], W + b))
```

as your loss already incorporates the sigmoid:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
```

I modified your code with the above changes (as well as couple additional changes in the printing section, to adjust the format), and got the following output (you can see that the predictions become perfect starting from the second printing segment):

```
Predictions:    [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]]
Labels:     [[ 1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]

Iteration: 0
Accuracy: 0.2
Loss: 3.27201

Predictions:    [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
Labels:     [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

Iteration: 1000
Accuracy: 1.0
Loss: 0.000647951

Predictions:    [[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]]
Labels:     [[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]]

Iteration: 2000
Accuracy: 1.0
Loss: 0.000801496

Predictions:    [[ 1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]
Labels:     [[ 1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]

Iteration: 3000
Accuracy: 1.0
Loss: 0.000515367

Predictions:    [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]
Labels:     [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]

Iteration: 4000
Accuracy: 1.0
Loss: 0.000312456

Predictions:    [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]
Labels:     [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]

Iteration: 5000
Accuracy: 1.0
Loss: 5.86302e-05

Predictions:    [[ 1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
Labels:     [[ 1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]

Iteration: 6000
Accuracy: 1.0
Loss: 5.79187e-05

Predictions:    [[ 1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]]
Labels:     [[ 1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]]

Iteration: 7000
Accuracy: 1.0
Loss: 0.000136576

Predictions:    [[ 1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.]]
Labels:     [[ 1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.]]

Iteration: 8000
Accuracy: 1.0
Loss: 4.11543e-05

Predictions:    [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]
Labels:     [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]

Iteration: 9000
Accuracy: 1.0
Loss: 7.28511e-06
```

Here is the modified code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import random

sequenceLength = 5     # Input Dimension
maxNum = 1000          # Must be >= than (sequenceLength - 1)
outputDim = 1
hiddenDim = 16
learningRate = 0.01
trainingIterations = 10000
batchSize = 10
displayStep = 1000

def generateData():
    data = []
    labels = []
    for _ in range(batchSize):
        type = (1 if random.random() < 0.5 else 0)
        temp = []
        if type == 1:
            labels.append([1])
            temp.append(random.randint(0, maxNum - sequenceLength + 1))
            for i in range(1, sequenceLength):
                temp.append(random.randint(temp[i - 1] + 1, maxNum - sequenceLength + i + 1))
            data.append(temp)
        if type == 0:
            labels.append([0])
            temp.append(random.randint(0 + sequenceLength - 1, maxNum))
            for i in range(1, sequenceLength):
                temp.append(random.randint( 0 + sequenceLength - i - 1, temp[i - 1] - 1))
            data.append(temp)
    return data, labels

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, sequenceLength], name="input")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, outputDim], name="label")

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hiddenDim, outputDim]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([outputDim]))

cell = rnn.BasicRNNCell(hiddenDim)
outputs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, [x], dtype=tf.float32)
prediction = tf.matmul(outputs[0], W + b)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learningRate).minimize(loss)

correctPrediction = tf.equal(tf.round(tf.sigmoid(prediction)), y)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPrediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(trainingIterations):
        batchX, batchY = generateData()
        dict = {x: batchX, y : batchY}
        session.run(optimiser, feed_dict=dict)
        if i % displayStep == 0:
            print("Predictions:\t" + str(session.run(tf.transpose(tf.round(tf.sigmoid(prediction))), dict)))
            print("Labels:\t\t" + str(session.run(tf.transpose(y), dict)) + "\n")
            batchAccuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=dict)
            batchLoss = session.run(loss, feed_dict=dict)
            print("Iteration: " + str(i) + "\nAccuracy: " + str(batchAccuracy) + "\nLoss: " + str(batchLoss) + "\n")
```

Comment: Ok great, I had only considered increasing the learning rate in order for the model to "forget" that it had learned to classify every sequence as decreasing. However, my `loss` calculation is still incorrect. If you uncomment the last three lines you will see that `accuracy` is calculated perfectly, but `loss` always converges to `0.5`. I am presuming that this has to to with the predictions being either `0` or `1`, but it doesn't make sense why this would converge to `0.5`, even when it is predicting correctly 100% of the seqeunces.

Comment: If the accuracy for a batch is `1.0`, then the (rounded) prediction for every sequence in that batch was correct, and so the mean of all the losses shiuld certainly be less than `0.5`, and presumably move towards `0.0` as the model learns better and better?

Comment: One last side question: I have noticed that changing the batch size makes substantial differences in the model's ability to learn. I was unsure as to how TensorFlow processes each batch and subsequently when it applies the optimizer in this loop. Too small a batch causes very poor learning. So, does each batch go through the network and then the weighted matrices are tuned according to the total loss over the entire batch? This seems to contradict my belief that there is an entire forward and back propagation done for each sequence - the backprop being where the weights are adjusted.

Comment: @KOB yes indeed each batch goes through the network. The gradients are updated based on each batch. Thus, small batch may lead you in the "wrong" direction, which in its turn can cause the behavior that you see. You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437467/when-does-tensorflow-update-weights-and-biases

Comment: You have been a great help. Thank you.